# NLContextualEmbedding neighbors in Swift?

Tags: swift, nlp

Say I have some contextual embedding in Swift is there a way to find the neighbors? This already exists as a thing for NLEmbedding but that's not contextual. I feel like I might even be not fully understanding contextual embeddings since they do slightly confuse me but is this something that is possible right now? I checked the docs and couldn't really find anything for neighbors for NLContextualEmbedding.

Comment: I guess this would be kind of hard to do though as obviously it all depends on the context so if you have some very specific sentence it's not as easy as finding the neighbor for some static embedding now you have this contextual embedding in a very specific area and you can't realistically check all the different words I guess?